# Blackberry - How to render PDF document?

Tags: pdf, blackberry

How can I read .pdf file in BlackBerry through your own application?

Comment: PDFs are meant to be read by people, not applications.

Comment: hmm what is adobe acrobat reader do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API, nor lib to do such thing in blackberry.

However you can try to integrate [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) or [www.docspal.com](http://www.docspal.com/) or other server side rendering service.

Answer (score 0):

use google viewer inside your Browserfield, that will do the trick! =D!

```
public ScrLoad()
{     
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://prueba.agenciareforma.com/appiphone/android/elnorte.pdf";                
    add(new BrowserField(url));        
}
```

Google Docs Viewer http://docs.google.com/gview