# PDF Viewer for Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry

Are there any open source BlackBerry PDF renderer application. I have searched for PDF viewer, could not find any. Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Comment: When you say "open source", are you looking for code to add to an application you're creating or do you just want a free viewer?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060222/render-pdf-on-a-blackberry and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184229/blackberry-how-to-render-pdf-document

Comment: i need code for adding to an application we need to develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use google viewer inside your Browserfield, that will do the trick! =D!

```
public ScrLoad()
{     
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://prueba.agenciareforma.com/appiphone/android/elnorte.pdf";                
    add(new BrowserField(url));        
}
```

Google Docs Viewer http://docs.google.com/gview

Comment: hmm..I tested the link but its not working ..can you please let me know what excately the reason is..?

Comment: Anzy : add your own pdf address, http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=[ your own .pdf´s url]

Comment: ..I tried the same thing in Blackberry and Android platform , in Android it's showing the PDF View but in Blackberry the Browser Field try to load the the PDF but after some time it shows Blank Screen..

Comment: here is the URL https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.seca.com/fileadmin/media/products/seca_727/bda/BA_727_728_17-10-07-255j08_L_Druck_ohne_Freigabe.pdf

Answer (score 0):

JPedal:  http://www.jpedal.org/java_me_pdf_viewer.php

Comment: I have tried using JPedal but it was giving some issues. Thanks for the suggestion.