# How to display a .pdf on BrowserField in Blackberry 7

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to display a .pdf file on a browserfield but somehow it's not opening in my app however it works fine with .txt files.

I'm reading .pdf file from local storage and using

browser_field.displayContent(fileinbytes, "application/pdf", "");

but it's displaying a player like image on the screen and not actual result.

If anyone has any idea about the same, i'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this isn't possible (browserfield doesn't even fully support javascript).
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6140685/2415100) suggests that you can view it via Google, which wouldn't be from local storage.

(Un)luckily blackberry is very similar to Java ME, so you can often use those libraries as is. Apparently [JPedal](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/) can render pdf files for J2ME, and might be worth a look.

Other than that, I don't think you'll have much hope. Good luck